# How to trigger some action on recognization of imagetargets using Vuforia instead of teapot?

Tags: ios, integration, vuforia

i am integrating Vuforia SDK in my app. I have created the Image Targets from the Vuforia portal with images i have uploaded and i am able to draw teapot when it recognizes my images.But instead of drawing teapot i want to move to some view controller. How can i achieve that.please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple remark: using the Vuforia SDK only to do image recognition (without any tracking or augmented reality, which you seem to be wanting to do) is probably not the best choice, as the real strength of the Vuforia SDK is its augmented reality. You can probably find some more specialized image recognition SDK, that will be far lighter to use!

Comment: @mbrenon can you recommend me some image recognition SDK.

Comment: Well, SO is not supposed to be the place for that, but you can try [Moodstocks](http://www.moodstocks.com). Otherwise, a long list of image recognition APIs has been published today on [this page](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/09/09/37-recognition-apis-att-speech-moodstocks-and-rekognition/)

Comment: "View controller" means native iOS or 3d model animation?

Comment: native iOS as in new activity.

Comment: if you want I can post the answer. I have a simple solution for the same

Comment: thanks lokesh, but i found some solution..